# Can you turn a local network directory into a remote git repository?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a shared directory on a local network that is used for file storage and file sharing purposes. Is it possible to turn such a directory into a remote git repository so that I can push to it from a local git repository?

Comment: Yes créate a bare repo there you can push to

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it’s possible.

You can treat the shared directory as the local copy for the remote repo. Then you can push changes from the local repo to remote repo. Detail steps as below:

#### 1.   Create remote repo

You can setup remote repo on your own server by `git init --bare`.

And if the local machine can access to github, bitbucket etc. You can also hosted your remote repo there.

#### 2.   Setup local repo if you have not setup

In the shared directory, you should treat it as the local git repo. If you do not have local repo in the share directory, create and commit by:

```
# In the shared directory
git init
# If there has files which you do not want to commit in git repo, add a .gitignore to specify the files 
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
```

#### 3.   Add remote repo as remote for the local repo

To add the remote repo as a remote for the local repo and push changes to the remote repo, you can use below commands:

```
git remote add origin <URL for the remote repo>
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Getting the URL correct can be tricky. Something like this ```git remote add origin file:////host/share/blah/repo.git```

Comment: To specify the URL from shared path, the format should be `//host/share/blah/repo.git`.

Comment: Possibly because I was doing this on windows, I tried various things, and found I needed 4 slashes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have been unsuccessful so far. When I try to access the network directory where I want to create the remote repo, I am getting "CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories". I found online that this can be circumvented by mapping the network drive to a local drive but even after the mapping I am still not able to navigate to the directory. This might a security measure set up by our IT department so unrelated to my original question.

Comment: Still possible, but needs additional config for current git versions, and is a security risk, see (https://medium.com/@thecodinganalyst/git-detect-dubious-ownership-in-repository-e7f33037a8f), (https://github.com/git/git/commit/8959555cee7ec045958f9b6dd62e541affb7e7d9) and (https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2022-24765)

Answer (score 3):

The url for a local directory on linux uses : 'file' then 3 slashes so for example
`git remote add origin file:///home/mark/remote_repo`

Comment: emphasis on the three slashes